# How can I find out what is contained in a saved Docker image tar file?

Tags: json, docker

Let's say that I have saved one or more Docker images to a tar file, e.g.

```
docker save foo:1.2.0 bar:1.4.5 bar:latest > images.tar
```

Looking at the tar file, I can see that in addition to the individual layer directories, there is a `manifest.json` file that contains some meta information about the archives contents, including a `RepoTags` array for each image:

```
[{
  "Config": "...",
  "Layers": [...],
  "RepoTags": [
    "foo:1.2.0"
  ]
},
{
  "Config": "...",
  "Layers": [...],
  "RepoTags": [
    "bar:latest",
    "bar:1.4.5"
  ]
}]
```

Is there an easy way to extract that info from the tar file, e.g. through a Docker command - or do I have to extract the `manifest.json` file, run it through a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and then collect the tag info myself?

The purpose is to find out what is contained in the archive before importing/loading it on a different machine. I imagine that there must be some way to find out what's in the archive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I have not received any answers so far, I'll try to answer myself using what I have tried, and it's working for me.

Using a combination of `tar` and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), I came up with this command:

```
tar -xzOf images.tar.gz manifest.json | jq '[.[] | .RepoTags] | add'
```

This will extract the `manifest.json` file to `stdout`, pipe it into in the `jq` command, and jq combines the various `RepoTags` arrays into a single array:

```
[
  "foo:1.2.0",
  "bar:1.4.5",
  "bar:latest"
]
```

The result is easy to read and works for me. Only downside is that it requires an installation of `jq`. I would love to have something that works without dependencies.

Still looking for a better answer, don't hesitate to post an answer if you have something that's easier to use!

Comment: Working on json in bash without jq is miserable. Usually I avoid added dependencies also, but in this case I'd advise you take the dependency.

Comment: If you add another | .[] to your jq pipe, you'll get just a quoted list which may be easier to deal with.